# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined : Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

As I mentioned in my title I got this console error when I get data from two input fields on a button click.

```
<mat-form-field class="col-sm-12">
        <mat-label>Enter email</mat-label>
        <input #fileInput1 [readonly]="isSignUpEmailChange" #mEmail matInput pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" [formControl]="signUpEmail"
            placeholder="Email" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="signUpEmail.errors?.required">Please fill out this field</mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="signUpEmail.errors&&signUpEmail.errors.pattern">Enter the valid email</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field *ngIf="isNewMail" class="col-sm-12">
    <mat-label>Set password</mat-label>
    <input #mPassword #fileInput2 matInput placeholder="Password" [pattern]="selectedPattern" [formControl]="signInPassword" placeholder="Password"
        required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="signInPassword.errors?.required">Please fill out this field</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="signInPassword.errors&&signInPassword.errors.pattern">{{errorMgs}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here #fileInput1,#fileInput2 are used to programmatically click this fields based on some conditions

```
@ViewChild('fileInput1') fileInput1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('fileInput2') fileInput2: ElementRef;

delay(1000).then(_ => { this.fileInput1.nativeElement.click() });
delay(1000).then(_ => { this.fileInput1.nativeElement.click() });
```

Here I need to get the email and password values on a button click

```
<button
    (click)="signUp(mEmail.value,mPassword.value)"
    [disabled]="signInPassword.invalid"
    class="loginBtn"
    style="margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px;margin-top:10px"
    mat-raised-button color="warn"
>
Signup
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **hidden** instead of ***ngIf** for password input

ngIf remove the element from DOM and that is why you can access **mPassword.value**

like,

```
<mat-form-field [hidden]="!isNewMail" class="col-sm-12">
    <mat-label>Set password</mat-label>
        <input #mPassword #fileInput2 matInput placeholder="Password" [pattern]="selectedPattern" [formControl]="signInPassword" placeholder="Password"
                        required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="signInPassword.errors?.required">Please fill out this field</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="signInPassword.errors&&signInPassword.errors.pattern">{{errorMgs}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother @AniketAvhad